# Uncrustify file association

Tags: visual-studio-code, uncrustify

Is there a way to configure uncrustify to associate a specific language to a custom file extension?

I am using visual studio code on Linux with the uncrustify plugin. Formatting works perfectly if I rename a .groovy file to .java.

I would like to be able to configure uncrustify to associate .groovy files to java language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this'll do... Add to your `settings.json`:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.groovy": "java"
}
```